# If Zero solution is asymptotically stable, How to prove $\lim_{t \to +\infty} \|\Phi(t)\|=0$?

Tags: dynamical-systems

The system is $$\frac{d x}{d t} =A(t) x,\quad A(t)=(a_{ij}(t))_{n\times n}$$

$ \Phi(t)$ is the fundamental solution of the system. If zero solution is asymptotically stable, How to prove
$$
\lim_{t \to +\infty} \|\Phi(t)\|=0
$$

I know the conclusion can prove the assumption. But I can't prove the above proposition by myself.

Asymptotic Stability of zero solution:

Suppose $x(t,t_0, x_0)=\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(t_0)x_0$ is the solution of the system,
$$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta = \delta(\varepsilon), s.t. \|x_0\|<  \delta \ \&\ t>t_0, \|x(t,t_0, x_0)\| \leq \varepsilon . $$

Comment: Don´t You mean $\lim_{\color{red}t\rightarrow \infty}...$?

Comment: You can get proper norm bars $\|$ by using `\|` rather than `||`.

Comment: Depends entirely on your definition of asymptotically stable...

Comment: Can you write $x(t)$ using $\Phi(t)$ and $x_0$? It should hold for all possible $x_0$

Comment: I revised my question.